# Magento Layered Navigation (Manadev.com) ia acting strange with configurable products

Tags: magento, configurable-product, layered-navigation

I am using Manadev SEO Layered Navigation Plus (http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus) as my layered navigation, but it's acting strange with configurable products.

My configurable products use only one attribute to create configurables (Size). However I have a Color attribute, also used in the layered navigation (dropdown not used to create configuragles, because every product comes in one color and many sizes).

The problem is that Size attribute shows all the simples of the configurable product, even if they are disabled in the admin. When you see the product page, the disabled simples are not showing up, but they do in the layered navigation. What do you think may be the problem?

Btw I may have imported values for Color in the configurable product as well as in it's simples. And Re-Indexing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

SEO Layered Navigation Plus extension relies on standard Magento functionality which prepares special index tables for use in layered navigation (and decides which products should be shown when an option is selected). Unfortunately, this functionality does not consider quantity of simple products when preparing index tables for configurable products.

Standard Magento layered navigation has the same issue because it relies on the same indexes.

There is no quick fix. We consider altering Magento indexing functionality to address this issue.

To keep you posted on this issue please contact us through www.manadev.com website.

Comment: Yes, I know that quantity of simple products are not considered, but shouldn't simple products be excluded from the layered navigation, when they have STATUS set to DISABLED in the backend?